# Windows program to compress javascript and minify images

Tags: javascript, css, minify, compression

I just came accross this program for Mac/Apple

http://incident57.com/codekit/

In short, it will

- compile .LESS, .SASS, .SCSS files into pure CSS files
- Minify Javascript files
- Optimize images

All in one program, this is great for something like a build script to use.

I am looking for a program that will run on Windows that will do stuff like this, preferably one for command line use so I can use a build script to automate it.

Have you heard of anything?

Comment: I suppose using a Mac is not an option...?

Comment: Why do you need just one program to do all this? There are individual programs that do each of those things, and if you're scripting it what difference does it make if you're using three programs or one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your website uses .net you might try RequestReduce. Currently it does this on the fly at runtime (using caching). Its currently not setup to do this at build time. It minimizes and combines CSS and JS, compiles Sass/Less and Coffee script and it sprites and optimizes css background images. For the sass/less/coffee see the RequestReduce.SassLessCoffee package. There are plans to provide a build time option but the advantage of runtime is the ability to process resources dynamically generated like WebResources and ScriptResources or Scripts on another host. Check out http://www.RequestReduce.com for more info.